# Growing an object type dynamically at run time using Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to be able to create a *configurator* which allows the run-time to build up a set of properties on an object and then return that config as a strongly typed object when complete. I had started out thinking this wouldn't be hard but I am really struggling to get it to work.

Here's the code currently:

```
export type InferredRecord<T> = T extends Record<string, infer R>
  ? Record<string, R>
  : Record<string, unknown>;

export const Configurator = <I, IR extends Record<string, I>>(initial?: InferredRecord<IR>) => {
  const API = <T, C extends Record<string, T>>(current: InferredRecord<C>) => {
    console.log(current);

    return {
      add: <AT, AR extends Record<string, AT>>(v: InferredRecord<AR>) => {
        return API({ ...v, ...current });
      },
      done() {
        return { ...current };
      },
      currentValue() {
        return current;
      },
    };
  };

  return API(initial || {});
};
```

While I have had it return the right value before, currently not even that works. The `console.log()` statement actually shows it working (aka, accumulating values):

[image]

but when I call `done()` or `currentValue()` I only get the initial value passed into the configurator. These results and my testing are driven off the following test:

[image]

I've included the screenshots as they display -- in blue -- the outputs of the console.logs i'm scattered around.

---

Note: the next code snippet does return the right information when you call `done()` but the typing is still wrong (type is an empty object `{}`);

```
export const Configurator = <I>(initial?: InferredRecord<I>) => {
  const API = <C>(current: InferredRecord<C>) => {
    console.log(current);

    return {
      add: <A>(v: InferredRecord<A>) => {
        current = { ...v, ...current };
        return API({ ...v, ...current });
      },
      done() {
        return { ...current };
      },
      currentValue() {
        return current;
      },
    };
  };
  return API(initial || {});
};
```

p.s. making the value return correctly is primarily a matter of adding the `current = { ...v, ...current };` line which ... feels like it should NOT be necessary (or even desirable).

---

Final note: in sheer typing desperation I tried to explicitly type the recursive API call with the intersection of generic types A and C::

[image]

made no difference.

---

Experimenting with the use of an inference type of this variety:

```
export type InferredObject<T> =
  | {
      [K in keyof T]: T[K];
    }
  | {};
```

I realized that use of `Record` was likely getting in the way of my intended goal of having strong typing for the full structure is my goal.

Not sure if i've explained myself clearly but getting very tired; will probably need to get some zzz's.

Comment: I’ve answered a similar question before and the key is that the object you return has different values for the generics than it did before.

Comment: Please include code and output as text directly in the question, not as images. It would also be best if you could reduce this to a [mcve] since your code seems to have some parts that are not required to demonstrate or reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The key to properly typing this is that that the object returned from calling `add()` has a different generic than the previous object.

Let's think about what adding does to the generics.  Say that you start out with a `Record<string, string>` `{a: "a"}`.  Then you add a `Record<string, boolean>` `{b: false}`.  Your new object is `{a: "a", b: false}` which is `Record<string, string | boolean>`.  So basically we need to combine `A` and `C` with an `OR`.

```
interface API<C> {
  add<A>(v: Record<string, A>): API<A | C>;
  done(): Record<string, C>;
  currentValue(): Record<string, C>;
}

const API = <C>(current: Record<string, C>) => {
  return {
    add: <A>(v: Record<string, A>): API<A | C> => {
      return API({ ...v, ...current });
    },
    done() {
      return { ...current };
    },
    currentValue() {
      return current;
    },
  };
};

const value = API({ a: "a" }).add({ b: false }).done();
// type is {[x: string]: string | boolean;}
```

Note: I'm not sure why you have both `done()` and `currentValue()` when they are the same.

Your `Configurator` creates problems due to the optional argument, which makes it such that it always creates `API<unknown>`.  For this reason I separated the `Configurator` from the `API` portion and implemented `Configurator` with function overloads.

In order to get the right typings when adding values to an object which starts out empty, I used `API<never>` instead of `API<unknown>` because the `never` will be dropped from a union (`string | never` is `string`) whereas `unknown` takes priority (`string | unknown` is `string`).

```
function Configurator<I>(initial: Record<string, I>): API<I>
function Configurator(): API<never>
function Configurator<I>(initial?: Record<string, I>) {
  return API(initial || {});
};

const value1 = Configurator({ a: "a" }).add({ b: false }).done();
// type is Record<string, string | boolean>

const value2 = Configurator().add({ b: false }).done();
// type is Record<string, boolean>
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/RwRxxm)

### Edit

You now want the object type to have types for each specific key rather than just a `Record`.  This is mostly a very minor change.  We make our generics `C`, `A` and `I` represent the object itself rather than the value type of the `Record`.

```
interface API<C extends {} = {}> {
  add<A extends {}>(v: A): API<A & C>;
  done(): C;
}

const API = <C,>(current: C) => {
  return {
    add<A extends {}>(v: A): API<A & C> {
      return API({ ...v, ...current });
    },
    done() {
      return current;
    }
  };
};

function Configurator<I extends {}>(initial: I): API<I>
function Configurator(): API<{}>
function Configurator<I extends {}>(initial?: I) {
  return API(initial || {});
};

const value1 = Configurator({ a: "a" }).add({ b: false }).done();
// type is { b: boolean; } & { a: string; }

const value2 = Configurator().add({ b: false }).done();
// type is { b: boolean; }
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/qNBLnW)

When adding an `A` object to a `C` object, we get `A & C` -- mostly.  `API<A & C>` would work 99% of the time, but if we want to support the last 1% of cases then we need to think a little bit deeper.  If `A` & `C` have a property which is incompatible, like `{c: boolean}` and `{c: string}`, then `A & C` would give us `{c: never}`.  But that's not what the function returns.  Order matters here, but the spread that you have written `({ ...v, ...current })` means that the properties of `C` would override those of `A`.  So the true type is `API<C & Omit<A, keyof C>>`.  Annoyingly, typescript sees the type as `A & C`, so even though the `Omit` version is more accurate it actually requires an `as` assertion.

```
add<A extends {}>(v: A): API<C & Omit<A, keyof C>> {
  return API({ ...v, ...current } as C & Omit<A, keyof C>);
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/rw2Vjw)

Consider this example.  The first value for `a` is kept, so the returned object is `{a: "a"}`.

```
const value3 = Configurator({ a: "a" }).add({ a: false }).done();
```

With the `A & C` version, the type of `value3` is `never` -- which is wrong.  With the `Omit` we get `{ a: string; } & Pick<{ a: boolean; }, never>` which is complicated but it is actually accurate as that type is the same as `{ a: string; }`.

Honestly I would go with the `A & C` version for the sake of simplicity, unless your use case requires type overriding.

Comment: This is a big step in the right direction. Ignore my currentValue() nonsense, that warped as the madness grew ... there was an earlier hour where there was distinction between it and the `done()` call. :)

One thing I'm realizing is that what ai really want is to move away from Record based types. I want to have explicit typing for each property added to the configuration. I'm hoping that this is an option ... do you have any opinion?

Comment: Basically what I'd ideally like in your **value1** example is to have the type end up as: `{ a: string, b: boolean } `

Comment: I added a little comment to the end of the question, to illustrate where my head's going.

Comment: Yes it’s definitely doable to have specific interfaces.  I can update my answer tomorrow.  Basically it’s the same idea: if you had API<T> and you add N then you get API<T & N>.

Comment: Just updated.  It's basically simple unless you want to make it complicated lol.

Comment: Fantastic; thanks. I can live with the A&C simplification but the additional detail is still helpful.